# check if a tree is a binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I have written the following code to check if a tree is a Binary search tree. Please help me check the code:

Okay! The code is edited now. This simple solution was suggested by someone in the posts below:

```
IsValidBST(root,-infinity,infinity);

bool IsValidBST(BinaryNode node, int MIN, int MAX) 
{
     if(node == null)
         return true;
     if(node.element > MIN 
         && node.element < MAX
         && IsValidBST(node.left,MIN,node.element)
         && IsValidBST(node.right,node.element,MAX))
         return true;
     else 
         return false;
}
```

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad - what language is this written in?  It would be extremely helpful if you edit your question to tag your question appropriately.  Also, you should use the code tag buttons (`{}`) to format your code for easier readability.  Finally, what is wrong with your code?  What exactly are we "checking" for, are you getting an error?

Comment: this is java code, and i am checking whether a BinaryNode v satisfied the properties of a binary search tree

Comment: @TimeToCode, why do you return a `Pair()` ??

Comment: @muggen:cuz i need to keep track of max and min values

Comment: @TimeToCode , for the whole tree ? Are you looking the smallest and biggest number in the whole tree?

Comment: @Muggen: for each subtree                                                       @Petars: DO NOT USE THIS POST TO CHAT WTIH BOBS

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad - I just made a joke:) You probably know who is Bobby Tables - http://xkcd.com/327/ :)

Comment: @TimeToCode, I think the way you do it, you will only get the `Min` and `Max` for the Whole Tree, not each subtree.

Comment: @Muggen: I modified the code..please let me know if you think it works

Comment: @TimeToCode, do you really have to return a Pair ? Generally it should be avoided for one method to do more than one thing. I think you should have one method that checks if it is indeed a BST, and another one that finds the Min and Max of each Subtree.

Comment: @TimeToCode , eg, you could have a method `isBinarySearchTree()` which checks if a tree is indeed a BST, and then after you make it sure, use a different method called `GetSubTreeValues()` which will put all values in an `ArrayList` for each sub tree.

Comment: @TimeToCode, it would be way easier then, and it would also be more and look more correct. This code looks very complicated and I don't think it does what you want at all.

Comment: @TimeToCode, I need to go now, so I will leave what I think you should do. Hope it helps. Remember! Each method == One Action :) Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @TimeToCode, fixed something small on the code! There was a bug on `GetSubTreeValues()`

Comment: What if there are duplicate entries in the tree? Shouldn't it be <= Max and >= Min.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Method should only do one thing at a time. Also the way you do things are generally Weird.
I will give you some **almost-Java pseudocode**. Sorry for that, but I have not touched Java for some Time. I hope it helps. Look at the comments I also did on the Question and I hope you sort it out!

Call your isBST like that :

```
public boolean isBst(BNode node)
{
    return isBinarySearchTree(node , Integer.MIN_VALUE , Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Internally :

```
public boolean isBinarySearchTree(BNode node , int min , int max)
{
    if(node.data < min || node.data > max)
        return false;
    //Check this node!
    //This algorithm doesn't recurse with null Arguments.
    //When a null is found the method returns true;
    //Look and you will find out.
    /*
     * Checking for Left SubTree
     */
    boolean leftIsBst = false;
    //If the Left Node Exists
    if(node.left != null)
    {
        //and the Left Data are Smaller than the Node Data
        if(node.left.data < node.data)
        {
            //Check if the subtree is Valid as well
            leftIsBst = isBinarySearchTree(node.left , min , node.data);
        }else
        {
            //Else if the Left data are Bigger return false;
            leftIsBst = false;
        }
    }else //if the Left Node Doesn't Exist return true;
    {
        leftIsBst = true;
    }

    /*
     * Checking for Right SubTree - Similar Logic
     */
    boolean rightIsBst = false;
    //If the Right Node Exists
    if(node.right != null)
    {
        //and the Right Data are Bigger (or Equal) than the Node Data
        if(node.right.data >= node.data)
        {
            //Check if the subtree is Valid as well
            rightIsBst = isBinarySearchTree(node.right , node.data+1 , max);
        }else
        {
            //Else if the Right data are Smaller return false;
            rightIsBst = false;
        }
    }else //if the Right Node Doesn't Exist return true;
    {
        rightIsBst = true;
    }

    //if both are true then this means that subtrees are BST too
    return (leftIsBst && rightIsBst);
}
```

Now : If you want to find the `Min` and `Max` Values of each Subtree you should use a Container (I used an `ArrayList`) and store a triplet of `Node, Min, Max` which represents the root node and the values (obviously).

eg.

```
/*
 * A Class which is used when getting subTrees Values
 */
class TreeValues
{
    BNode root; //Which node those values apply for
    int Min;
    int Max;
    TreeValues(BNode _node , _min , _max)
    {
        root = _node;
        Min = _min;
        Max = _max;
    }
}
```

And a :

```
/*
 * Use this as your container to store Min and Max of the whole
 */
ArrayList<TreeValues> myValues = new ArrayList<TreeValues>;
```

Now this is a method which finds the `Min` and `Max` values of a given node:

```
/*
 * Method Used to get Values for one Subtree
 * Returns a TreeValues Object containing that (sub-)trees values
 */ 
public TreeValues GetSubTreeValues(BNode node)
{
    //Keep information on the data of the Subtree's Startnode
    //We gonna need it later
    BNode SubtreeRoot = node;

    //The Min value of a BST Tree exists in the leftmost child
    //and the Max in the RightMost child

    int MinValue = 0;

    //If there is not a Left Child
    if(node.left == null)
    {
        //The Min Value is this node's data
        MinValue = node.data;
    }else
    {
        //Get me the Leftmost Child
        while(node.left != null)
        {
            node = node.left;
        }
        MinValue = node.data;
    }
    //Reset the node to original value
    node = SubtreeRoot; //Edit - fix
    //Similarly for the Right Child.
    if(node.right == null)
    {
        MaxValue = node.data;
    }else
    {
        int MaxValue = 0;
        //Similarly
        while(node.right != null)
        {
            node = node.right;
        }
        MaxValue = node.data;
    }
    //Return the info.
    return new TreeValues(SubtreeRoot , MinValue , MaxValue);   
}
```

But this returns Values for one Node only, So we gonna use this to find for the Whole Tree:

```
public void GetTreeValues(BNode node)
{
    //Add this node to the Container with Tree Data 
    myValues.add(GetSubTreeValues(node));

    //Get Left Child Values, if it exists ...
    if(node.left != null)
        GetTreeValues(node.left);
    //Similarly.
    if(node.right != null)
        GetTreeValues(node.right);
    //Nothing is returned, we put everything to the myValues container
    return; 
}
```

Using this methods, your call should look like

```
if(isBinarySearchTree(root))
    GetTreeValues(root);
//else ... Do Something
```

This is almost Java. It should work with some modification and fix. Find a good OO book, it will help you. Note, that this solution could be broke down into more methods.

Comment: @Muggen: i think your method to check isBST() is wrong. Try it on this tree:   root node: 10, then children of root node are 9 and 12. Then children of 9 are 8 and 40. this is not a BST but your code says it is!!!  if you agree, pls give me some credit and remove the -1

Comment: @TimeToCode, which is the Root ?

Comment: @TimeToCode I didn't give you the -1. I see what the problem is. Let me check and I will let you know.

Comment: @TimeToCode , Try it now, becareful of the edit : use `isBst(node)` !!

Comment: @TimeToCode, If I knew from the start what you were trying to do clearly I would have do it better. Try to give the examples from start.

Comment: @Muggen: ya, now it looks right :). I assume that for the left subtree you call isBST(v.left, min, v.data). Thanks for the advice. From next time , i will definitely give more examples. Thanks for your time and patience. moreover, for the right subtree, i think isBST(v.right, v.data, max) will also work. Overall, your logic seems cool and quite straightforward. Thanks a lot for your help again. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @TimeToCode, sure np. Have fun!

Comment: The last argument to the initial call of isBst, should be Integer.MAX_VALUE instead if Integer.MIN_VALUE

Answer (score 11):

right, another simple solution is do an inorder visit

[java code here](http://alexcode.tumblr.com/question_3)

Comment: This fails for certain test cases. Don't go with this solution though it looks cool. Check here for answer. https://metamug.com/blog/common-binary-tree-questions-java and related binary tree problems.

Answer (score 5):

```
boolean bst = isBST(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

public boolean isBST(Node root, int min, int max) {
    if(root == null) 
        return true;

    return (root.data > min &&
            root.data < max &&
            isBST(root.left, min, root.data) &&
            isBST(root.right, root.data, max));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** I just saw that this solution was suggested before. Sorry about this guys, maybe somebody still finds my version useful

Here is a solution that uses **[In-Order Traversal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0f6zZJy_A0)** to check for BST property.
Before I provide the solution, I am using a definition of a BST that doesn't allow duplicates. This means that each value in the BST is unique (this is just for simplicity).

Code for recursive inorder print:

```
void printInorder(Node root) {
    if(root == null) {                 // base case
        return;
    }
    printInorder(root.left);           // go left
    System.out.print(root.data + " "); // process (print) data
    printInorder(root.right);          // go right
}
```

After this inorder traversal on a BST, all the data should be printed in sorted ascending order.
For example the tree:

```
   5
 3   7
1 2 6 9
```

would have inorder print:

```
1 2 3 5 6 7 9
```

Now, instead of printing the node, we can keep track of the previous value in the In-Order sequence and compare it to the current node's value. If the current node's value is smaller than the previous value, this means that the sequence isn't in the ascending sorted order and that the BST property is violated.

For example, the tree:

```
   5
 3   7
1 8 6 9
```

Has a violation. The right child of **3** is **8** and this would be ok if **3** was the root node. However, in a BST **8** would end up as a left child of **9** and not as a right child of **3**. Therefore, this tree is not a BST.
So, the code that follow this idea:

```
/* wrapper that keeps track of the previous value */
class PrevWrapper {
    int data = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}

boolean isBST(Node root, PrevWrapper prev) {
    /* base case: we reached null*/
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if(!isBST(root.left, prev)) {
        return false;
    }
    /* If previous in-order node's data is larger than
     * current node's data, BST property is violated */
    if (prev.data > root.data) {
        return false;
    }

    /* set the previous in-order data to the current node's data*/
    prev.data = root.data;

    return isBST(root.right, prev);
}

boolean isBST(Node root) {
    return isBST(root, new PrevWrapper());
}
```

The in-order traversal for the sample tree would fail the check for node **5** since previous in-order of **5** is **8**, which is larger so BST property is violated.

Comment: Good of you to check whether an answer has been there before _and marking it as such at the beginning_ (seriously, even if several minutes late :-).

Answer (score 2):

```
    boolean isBST(TreeNode root, int max, int min) {
        if (root == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (root.val >= max || root.val <= min) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return isBST(root.left, root.val, min) && isBST(root.right, max, root.val);
        }

    }
```

an alternative way solving this problem.. similar with your code

Answer (score 1):

A binary search tree has the following properties where the key for the left node must be <= the root node key and the right node key must be greater that the root.

So the problem we have is if the keys in the tree are not unique and a in order traversal was done we could get a situation of two in order traversals producing the same sequence, where 1 would be a valid bst and the other would not, this would happen if we had a tree where the left node = root(valid bst) and the right node = root(invalid not a bst).

To get around this we need to maintain a valid min/max range that the key being 'visited' must fall between, and we pass this range as we recurse to other nodes.

```
#include <limits>

int min = numeric_limits<int>::min();
int max = numeric_limits<int>::max();

The calling function will pass the above min and max values initially to isBst(...)

bool isBst(node* root, int min, int max)
{
    //base case
    if(root == NULL)
        return true;

    if(root->val <= max && root->val >= min)
    {
        bool b1 = isBst(root->left, min, root->val);
        bool b2 = isBst(root->right, root->val, max);
        if(!b1 || !b2)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make much sense to return INTEGER.MIN,INTEGER.MAX as the values for an empty tree. Perhaps use an Integer and return null instead.

Comment: @anonymous:Why -1. pls justify because this is unacceptable. I am trying so hard to get the thing right and you just give a -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void inorder()
     {
         min=min(root);
         //System.out.println(min);
         inorder(root);

     }

     private int min(BSTNode r)
         {

             while (r.left != null)
             {
                r=r.left;
             }
          return r.data;


     }


     private void inorder(BSTNode r)
     {

         if (r != null)
         {
             inorder(r.getLeft());
             System.out.println(r.getData());
             if(min<=r.getData())
             {
                 System.out.println(min+"<="+r.getData());
                 min=r.getData();
             }
             else
             System.out.println("nananan");
             //System.out.print(r.getData() +" ");
             inorder(r.getRight());
             return;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

We do a depth-first walk through the tree, testing each node for validity as we go. A given node is valid if it's greater than all the ancestral nodes it's in the right sub-tree of and less than all the ancestral nodes it's in the left-subtree of. Instead of keeping track of each ancestor to check these inequalities, we just check the largest number it must be greater than (its lowerBound) and the smallest number it must be less than (its upperBound).

```
 import java.util.Stack;

final int MIN_INT = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
final int MAX_INT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public class NodeBounds {

BinaryTreeNode node;
int lowerBound;
int upperBound;

public NodeBounds(BinaryTreeNode node, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    this.node = node;
    this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
    this.upperBound = upperBound;
}
}

public boolean bstChecker(BinaryTreeNode root) {

// start at the root, with an arbitrarily low lower bound
// and an arbitrarily high upper bound
Stack<NodeBounds> stack = new Stack<NodeBounds>();
stack.push(new NodeBounds(root, MIN_INT, MAX_INT));

// depth-first traversal
while (!stack.empty()) {
    NodeBounds nb = stack.pop();
    BinaryTreeNode node = nb.node;
    int lowerBound = nb.lowerBound;
    int upperBound = nb.upperBound;

    // if this node is invalid, we return false right away
    if ((node.value < lowerBound) || (node.value > upperBound)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (node.left != null) {
        // this node must be less than the current node
        stack.push(new NodeBounds(node.left, lowerBound, node.value));
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        // this node must be greater than the current node
        stack.push(new NodeBounds(node.right, node.value, upperBound));
    }
}

// if none of the nodes were invalid, return true
// (at this point we have checked all nodes)
return true;
}
```