# check if a tree (nested list) is a binary search tree

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement the solution from here to R but I cannot figure out to how to properly do it in R

[check if a tree is a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575406/check-if-a-tree-is-a-binary-search-tree)

I converted this tree to a list:

```
1
/ \
2   2
/ \ / \
3  4 4  3

tree <- list("node"=1, "left"=list("node"=2, "left"=list("node"=3), "right"=list("node"=4)), "right"=list("node"=2, "left"=list("node"=3), "right"=list("node"=4)) )
```

using the `data.tree` package I can plot it:

```
> data.tree::FromListSimple(tree, nodeName = "1")
      levelName
1 1            
2  ¦--left     
3  ¦   ¦--left 
4  ¦   °--right
5  °--right    
6      ¦--left 
7      °--right
```

I tried to translate the Java version from the link above to R but I cannot get it to work:

```
isBST <- function(node, mini, maxi) {
  if(is.null(node)) return(TRUE)
  if(node < mini | node > maxi) return(FALSE)
  return(isBST(left, mini, node-1) & isBST(right, node+1, maxi))
}


isBST(tree, -10, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check if a tree is binary is simply:

```
tree$isBinary
```

The function takes advantage of the data.tree facility:

```
isBinary = function() {
    all(2 == Get(Traverse(self, filterFun = function(x) !x$isLeaf), "count"))
}
```

Obviously, you can also implement it yourself, e.g. with recursion as in the example linked. Though I would not recommend it, because recursion is typically slow in R.